# AndroidViewClient: giving import error

Tags: android, python, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I’ve downloaded from git the latest version [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient).
I did the easy_install method but I get

```
~/projects/AndroidViewClient-master/AndroidViewClient $ monkey runner examples/check-import.py
141022 11:55:48.708:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions] Script terminated due to an exception
141022 11:55:48.708:S [main] [com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerOptions]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/damonh/projects/AndroidViewClient-master/AndroidViewClient/examples/check-import.py", line 36, in <module>
    import com.dtmilano
ImportError: No module named dtmilano
```

I am running MAC OS X 10.9.   I really could use a little help here with this.  I tried doing the ant build method as well but get the same issues.
I am hoping you can help me out as this would facilitate testing.

Comment: Please convert this from an email thread into a proper SO question. And, if you have an answer, post it as an answer to your on question, not as part of the question

Comment: Will do so. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is still an unedited email thread, not a proper SO question.

Comment: @DamonHermann you can [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is Diego's response.

To verify that you have successfully installed AVC using easy_install, try:

```
$ culebra --version

culebra 8.5.0
```

Then, to run the examples obtained from the sources just cd to the directory and

```
$ ./check-import.py
OK
```

IMPORTANT: Lastest AVC versions don't use monkeyrunner, jython, java, etc., only python. 
Hope this helps.

---

BTW, you should also give the UI a try as it greatly simplifies test creation.
Once you have your device connected (showed by `adb devices`), run:

```
$ culebra -UG
```